# textarea doesn't inherit css color form parent element

Tags: css, inheritance, textarea

I have a textarea inside a div. The div css sets the color, but the textarea doesn't seem to react to that.

Is this the correct behavior ? 
how can I get the color property to apply from the div to the textarea ?

[here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/1j3kq6s0/)

```css
.c1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  An now for something completly different :<br/>
  <textarea>
          the news : spam spam spam spam spam
        </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea will not inherit until you mark it so

```
.c1 textarea{
    color:inherit;
}
```

So you can apply color for both `div` child and `textarea` fields. If I am not mistaking `input` tag also does not inherit color by `default`

Answer (score 1):

It's because textarea has default style applied by the browser so the inheritance will not work:

[image]

[image]

You need to specify a color for the textarea or use `inherit` to get the color of the div

```css
.c1 {
  color: red;
}
textarea {
 color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  An now for something completly different :<br/>
  <textarea>
          the news : spam spam spam spam spam
        </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below CSS.

```
.c1,textarea.classname {color:red;}
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not my point : I will have several textareas in several elements, each with different styles.. I don't wish to redefined each style for each textarea

Comment: you can add the class for textarea. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS Code

```
.c1,textarea {  
    color:red;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers gives default styles to inputs, buttons,...
So `Textarea` have `color:initial` set. You need to specify in your code the color for `Textarea`.

```
.c1,
textarea{
  color:red;
}
```